# std::invoke with ref qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++17, std-invoke

I'm running into the following issue when using ref qualifiers with `operator()` below. What is the correct syntax to enable the l-value ref overload in this instance?

```cpp
#include <functional>

struct F { 
   void operator()() &  {}
   void operator()() && {} // Commenting this overload enables code to compile
};

int main() { 
   F f;
   std::invoke(&F::operator(), f); 
}
```

Error

```cpp
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:10:15: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, F&)'
   10 |    std::invoke(&F::operator(), f);
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220731/include/c++/13.0.0/functional:107:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr std::invoke_result_t<_Fn, _Args ...> std::invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)'
  107 |     invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
      |     ^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220731/include/c++/13.0.0/functional:107:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:10:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
   10 |    std::invoke(&F::operator(), f);
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:10:15: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, F&)'
   10 |    std::invoke(&F::operator(), f);
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220731/include/c++/13.0.0/functional:107:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> constexpr std::invoke_result_t<_Fn, _Args ...> std::invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)'
  107 |     invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
      |     ^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20220731/include/c++/13.0.0/functional:107:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:10:15: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Callable'
   10 |    std::invoke(&F::operator(), f);
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first argument of `std::invoke`, which is expected to be a pointer to a member function.

As per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions):

> A pointer to function may be initialized from an overload set which may include functions, function template specializations, and function templates, if only one overload matches the type of the pointer

[cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address):

> The parameter types and the return type of the function must match the target exactly, no implicit conversions are considered

In your case, `&F::operator()` can't be deduced, you need to provide the type explicitly.

```
std::invoke<void(F::*)()&>(&F::operator(), f);
std::invoke<void(F::*)()&&>(&F::operator(), std::move(f));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5164z1Pqc)

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the answer provided by @Nimrod, the following explicit cast works as well.

```cpp
int main() { 
   F f;
   std::invoke(static_cast<void(F::*)()&>(&F::operator()), f); 
   std::invoke(static_cast<void(F::*)()&&>(&F::operator()), std::move(f)); 

}
```